# 99 Jetta - ":Three Tones and Flashing Brake Light

Tags: brakes, jetta

We just bought a 99 Jetta - Working on the bugs.

- With the emergency brake OFF, once I exceed 15 mph I hear 3 tones and the "brake" light starts flashing. Am I right to think it may be from an emerg. brake off switch not functioning? Where would I gain access to the switch to check it?

Any other suggestions?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The switch is usually somewhere under or behind the lever - you'll have to remove the trim around the lever to get to it. It'll be operated by a 'tab' on the lever itself.

However, on most cars I have dealt with, the 'brake' light will stay on constantly when the e-brake is engaged - so if the switch had failed, it would continue to remain on.

Have you checked the service brake for any issues? It might be detecting an imbalance between the circuits or similar?